# Authentication token refresh handling process

Tags: objective-c, authentication, process, refresh, token

My app communicates with a backend server. On every web-request, it is checked if the authentication token is valid. If not the App request a new token. This works fine in the first instance.

But now I have the dilemma, that the new token, will be delivered at some point in time. Until, this point in time has reached, the original request has to wait, repsective has to be notified that the new auth token is available and the request can proceed.

**How do I solve this dilemma? What is the best way to do a auth token refresh?**

Here's what I have currently done:

#### ViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

-(IBAction)sandbox;

@end
```

#### ViewController.m - with important parts

```c
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "WebApi.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

-(IBAction)sandbox {
    // Call the web request, if the auth token is expired
    // a new token shall be retrieved if allowed and proceed
    // with the web-request
    [[WebApi sharedInstance] sandbox]; 
}

@end
```

#### WebApi.h

```c
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.h"
#import "SingletonClass.h"

@interface WebApi : AFHTTPRequestOperationManager <SingletonDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) SingletonClass *sshare;

+(WebApi*)sharedInstance;

-(void)sandbox;
-(void)refreshVilitToken; 

@end
```

#### WebApi.m

```c
#import "WebApi.h"

#define kApiHost @"http://192.168.1.157"

@implementation WebApi

-(WebApi*)initWithBaseURL:url {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        self.sshare = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];
    }
    return  self;
}

+(WebApi*)sharedInstance
{
    static WebApi *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kApiHost]];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

-(void)sandbox {

    DLog(@"Sandbox call");

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/public/foo/sandbox", kApiHost];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [self setAuthHeader:manager];

    [manager GET:URLString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        DLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        DLog(@"Error: %@, responseString: %@", error, operation.responseString);
    }];
}

-(void)setAuthHeader:(AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *)manager {

    if (self.sshare.hasCredentialsExpired) { // if token is expired!
        [self refreshToken];  // get a new token
        self.sshare.delegate = self;
        self.sshare.tokenInRefreshProcess = YES;  // token retrieving is in process
       // If new token is retrived the variable is set to NO
    }

    if (!self.sshare.tokenInRefreshProcess) {  // if the new token is available, then ...
        // How do I ensure that this is proceeded first if the token is available?

        NSDictionary *access = self.sshare.getAccessCredentials;

        DLog(@"Token: %@ and id %@", access[@"token"], access[@"id"]);
        manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
        manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];    
        [manager.requestSerializer setAuthorizationHeaderFieldWithUsername:access[@"token"]
                                                                      password:access[@"id"]];
    }
}

-(void)refreshToken {
    DLog(@"%@", self.sshare.database[@"foo"]);

    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/public/foo/token/%@/%@", kApiHost, [self.sshare authKey], self.sshare.database[@"foo"][@"foo_refesh"]];
    DLog(@"URLString %@", URLString); 
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    [manager PUT:URLString parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        [self.sshare saveNewToken:responseObject];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        DLog(@"Error: %@, responseString: %@", error, operation.responseString);
    }];
}

// delegate, but I strugle to use this for every request...
// I could place here the -(void)sandbox call, but then I can only
// call this method, I want that this works for every web-request
-(void)didRefreshToken {
    DLog(@"DELEGATE     :: did refresh Vilit token!!");
}
```

Comment: why dont you perform the actual request first with token. If the request fails then request a new token and re-try the actual request again.

Comment: Workaround, but sounds a little bit odd. But all web-request are detachted, so they are answered in some point of time... not so good.

Comment: Use MKNetworkkit and call your requests in previous requests' callbacks